# Let $S_n$ be the sum of all integers $k$ such that $2^n<k<2^{n+1}$

Tags: inequality

Then $9$ divides $S_n$ if

a) $n$ is odd

b) $n$ is even

c) $n$ is of the form $3k +1$

d) $n$ is of the form $3k +2$

Comment: Sorry but where is the question here?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$S_n=(2^n+1)+(2^n+2)+\cdots+(2^n+(2^n-1))$

$=(2^n-1)2^n+\frac{(2^n-1)(2^n)}{2}$

$=3*2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$

Answer (score 0):

### Hint:

Use $\sum_{i=a}^b=\frac12(a+b)(b-a+1)$.

Then, $$S_n=\sum_{i=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}-1}=\frac12(2^n+1+2^{n+1}-1)(2^{n+1}-2^n-1)$$$$=\frac12(2^n(1+2))(2^n(2-1)-1)=2^{n-1}\cdot 3\cdot (2^{n}-1)$$

So, $9|S_n$ iff $3|2^n-1$. As $2\equiv -1\pmod3$.

$$2^n-1\equiv (-1)-1\equiv -2\pmod3\qquad \text{if $n$ is odd}$$
$$2^n-1\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\pmod3\qquad \text{if $n$ is even}$$

Thus, $9|S_n$ iff $n$ is even